# No progress feedback from NPM commands in Git Bash on Windows

Tags: git, npm, git-bash

On my new machine (windows 10) when I run NPM commands like `npm start` I don't see as much feedback as I used to.

I guess it is the progress indicator I am missing.  It often appears that nothing is happening, no feedback.

Especially when installing modules, it really looks like the thing has hung.  Eventually the command completes as normal.

Comment: Trying running the command with the verbose flag? `- -verbose`

Comment: @evolutionxbox That helped because at least there's more logging, but still not progress indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm has a [`progress`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#progress) configuration key. It is described as follows:

> **progress**
>
> - Default: true, unless TRAVIS or CI env vars set.
> - Type: Boolean
>
> When set to `true`, npm will display a progress bar during time intensive operations, if `process.stderr` is a TTY.
>
> Set to `false` to suppress the progress bar.

Perhaps it has inadvertently been set to `false`.

To `get`/`set` the `progress` configuration you can utilize the [npm-config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) command:

1. Check its current setting by running:

   ```
   npm config get progress
   ```
2. If the aforementioned command returns `false` then set it to `true` by running:

   ```
   npm config set progress true
   ```

---

#### Note: git-bash may be classified as a *"dumb terminal"*

I have git-bash installed on an earlier version of Windows and when I run:

```
npm config get progress
```

it returned:

> `undefined`

Setting it to `true` made no difference, i.e. it does not get a progress bar.

I assume [my terminal (git-bash) is dumb](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/597cc0e4b5e6ee719014e3171d4e966df42a275c), i.e. a progress bar is not supported. Yours may be dumb too !

Comment: Have to mention that personally the “npm config get progress” command returned true, yet I still don’t see the progress bar :/

Comment: @Martin - There was a known bug in npm `v7.7.0` that caused the progress bar to _NOT_ display _(see [issue #2926](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2926))_. It's fixed in `v7.7.3`, perhaps you need to upgrade to `>=7.7.3`.

Comment: thanks but actually it got resolved by upgrading to a newer Git for Windows version.