# npm install progress bar not showing in docker container

Tags: bash, docker, npm

I'm launching a bash script inside a container to do npm install but I can't see the progress bar

here's the docker command inside a bash script:

```
docker-compose run --rm my-docker-node-service \
  bash < npm-install-empty-node_modules
```

Here's the code for `npm-install-empty-node_modules`

```
if [ ! -d "node_modules" ]; then
  echo "node_modules folder doesn't exist"
  npm install
  exit 0
fi
```

it prints "node_modules folder doesn't exist" as well as everything else, just not the npm install progress bar, which makes it seem like it has frozen. But if you wait long enough it finished installing.

Comment: Maybe you need to add 'tty: true' in service definition?

Comment: same result with tty: true

Comment: Check the result of `npm config get progress` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586270/no-progress-feedback-from-npm-commands-in-git-bash-on-windows/59595219#59595219).

Comment: @RobC says 'true' but doesn't actually show the progress